# jQuery autocomplete autofocus not keeping up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When using a jQueryUI AutoComplete with AutoFocus set to true, if you type too quickly and hit enter, the first selection will replace what you typed, even if it doesn’t match.

For example, if you type in "app", and the first selection of the scrolling autocomplete is "apple", and then continue to type in "applique" quickly and hit enter, "applique" is replaced by "apple".

Immediately before the entered text is replaced by the first selection from the autocomplete, is there any way to make sure the first selection still matches the text entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decrease your delay in the autoComplete options.  If you're using local data, you can set the delay to 0.  By default, it's set to 300 (ms).  So, after you press a key, it takes 300ms before it re-evaluates the dataset for matches.

So, basically your autofocusing on the first item, and haven't given it a chance to refilter before hitting enter.

Alternatively, you could change the delay mid stream after the first autoFocus.  So, the first time you wait 300ms to show a suggestion, then in the focus event, you decrease the timer to 0ms so it'll filter the list faster.

Be careful though, as a delay of 0 could cause issues if it's remote data.  Something like this might work well:

```
$(".selector").autocomplete({
  delay: 300,
  focus: function () {
    $(".selector").autocomplete("option", "delay", 0);
  },
  source: sourceData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but this has been driving me crazy. I didn't want to change my delay, and even if I did, If i typed too fast it would still erase my last characters.

After a big headache, I found the best solution :)

Open your jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.js (cannot assure you the code will work in any other version) and then find this lines:

```
                blur: function( event, ui ) {
                // don't set the value of the text field if it's already correct
                // this prevents moving the cursor unnecessarily
                if ( self.menu.element.is(":visible") &&
                    ( self.element.val() !== self.term ) ) {
                    self.element.val( self.term );
                }
            }
```

Just comment out that `if statement` like this:

```
                blur: function( event, ui ) {
                // don't set the value of the text field if it's already correct
                // this prevents moving the cursor unnecessarily
                /*COMMENTING THIS IF OUT MAKES AUTOCOMPLETE STOP ERASING WHAT YOU TYPE
                if ( self.menu.element.is(":visible") &&
                    ( self.element.val() !== self.term ) ) {
                    self.element.val( self.term );
                }
                */
            }
```

and everything will work fine :)